# unable to get Pivot result in My Sql

Tags: mysql, pivot

If I have a MySQL table looking something like this:

```
SNO ProjectName StartDate   EndDate HoursWorked
-----------------------------------------------
1   VS          01-07-2014  01-07-2014  10
2   BSS         02-07-2014  02-07-2014  8
3   ICCS        03-07-2014  03-07-2014  8
4   VS          04-07-2014  04-07-2014  7
5   BSS         05-07-2014  05-07-2014  6
6   ICCS        06-07-2014  06-07-2014  9
7   VS          07-07-2014  07-07-2014  6
8   BSS         08-07-2014  08-07-2014  9
9   ICCS        09-07-2014  09-07-2014  10
10  VS          10-07-2014  10-07-2014  3
11  BSS         11-07-2014  11-07-2014  6
12  ICCS        12-07-2014  12-07-2014  8
13  VS          13-07-2014  13-07-2014  10
```

Is it possible to run a MySQL query to get output like this:

```
ProjectName 13-07-2014  07-07-2014  01-07-2014
----------------------------------------------
VS          13          13          10
BSS         15          14          0
ICCS        18          17          0
```

I will select startDate From UI i will have to get week wise result i.e previous 6 weeks values
Ex: if i select 13-07-2014 
need to get result from 11-06-2014 to 13-07-2014

Please some body help me.. I have been trying to get this but I'm not..I am a begineer to My Sql earlier I worked with SQL .. no Idea how to get this.

Thanks in Advance
Sorry for my bad english.
I am running out of time

Comment: Take a look to [this post](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) on how to build "pivot-like" queries in MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the replies... I couldn't do in MySQL so I have done it using c#